# How to parse JSON eliminating nullpointer exception

Tags: android, json, pointers, exception, null

I am trying to parse JSON by creating a JSON object from a result string, 
then parse it into a JSON array and looping through the it.

```
JSONObject jsonobject = new JSONObject(json_string)
```

`json_string` being the result of a URL execution. 
My JSON looks like this.

```
{"ResultO":[{"Surname":null,"Firstname":null,"NRC":null}]}
```

The line 
`JSONObject = new JSONObject` brings up a null pointer exception.
How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you sure that json_string is not null?

Comment: When I throw the string to a toast or text view, it shows, so I assume its not null

Comment: I've put everything in a try catch block, I hope that's not the issue

Comment: @Charles Wisdom Welcome to Stack Overflow.  It's going to be much easier for people to help with this if you provide an [mcve] as well as error output.  Please read [How to Ask a Good Question](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: please show us more code, I can't tell why you're getting the error. (ex. logcat stacktrace, what the code around the exception looks like...)

Comment: May be it's not your JSON response , are you sure ? is it response or you guess it ? please make sure. 

If it's response then put condition for every value where you use it .

Answer (score 0):

The exception is coming because your json_string is null or empty better you check `if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(json_string)) {}`before proceeding. If your key has null value as `key_value:null` then JSONObject never throws an exception instead it will set your value as String "null".